# How overwrite docs with scripts in google?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I make one script to auto fill a Google Doc from a Google Form Submissiom. Now I need another script to overwrite the document when there is a change in some spreadsheet value . (the user cannot edit the form's response but can change values ​​in the spreadsheet).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhpP5.png)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Please share your for submission script and spreadsheet that changes

Comment: thanks, print sent in the question.

Comment: Please share your for submission script and spreadsheet that changes and don't post the code as an image.  I don't follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: Sorry Cooper, but i don´t have a script, i need help to make one.

Comment: So did you lie when you said `I make one script to auto fill a Google Doc from a Google Form Submissiom. Now I need another` ?

Comment: No, if you see the question again and see the print, the first script is ok, perfect, it works. I need help for the second to overwrite the document.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know what paragraph it is that needs to be edited you can try this.

Before:

[image]

```
function myFunction() {
  try {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var paras = body.getParagraphs();
    var i = 0;
    for( i=0; i<paras.length; i+=2 ) {
      paras[i].setText("Line "+(100+i));
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i have one information in column "H" (status = open or close), and in column "I" The link for doc. How i make to this change in status (open or close) overwrite the field in the document?

Comment: If you know how you wrote the Doc, how come this doesn’t tell you how to edit it with new values?

Comment: Because the firts autofill come from google-forms, and now i want overwrite with change in spreadsheet.